# Filepath: use same filepath on Unix and Windows

Tags: windows, file, unix, file-io, samba

I am working on application which work on both Unix and Windows environment. I have mapped my Unix drive on Windows using Samba.  On Cygwin:

```
 ls -l /remote
 /remote -> //samba1
```

When I try following command:

```
myExecutable /remote/fileloc/filename.txt
```

It's working fine in Unix but failing on Windows during file opening. It works fine if I give the following command on Windows:

```
myExecutable //samba1/fileloc/filename.txt
```

Is there any way I can access with same path (`/remote/fileloc/filename.txt`) on both Unix and Windows?

**Edit**
I can change only in Windows. I can't change the Unix drive path.

Comment: Unix doesn't care if you write `//remote`; it means the same as `/remote`.  So, instead of using `/remote`, name it `/samba1`; then you can use `//samba1/fileloc/filename.txt` on both.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thx for info. But that is a "/remote" drive i can't change its name there any many dependancy i can change anything in windows only.

Comment: `ln -s /remote /samba1`.

Comment: while doing this it's giving "ln: failed to create symbolic link `/samba1': Permission denied"

Comment: Yes; only user root can trample in the root directory of your machines file system (unless the security is completely blown).